# Does Gmail IMAP use a self-signed SSL cert?

Tags: gmail, ssl, imap

I'm trying to set up Gmail using a desktop client, via IMAP. It works, except that my client is complaining about the SSL cert:

Issuer:            CN=Google Internet Authority,O=Google Inc,C=US
Subject:           CN=imap.gmail.com,O=Google Inc,L=Mountain View,ST=California,C=US
Fingerprint:       f4:3c:f0:30:6a:03:d4:5b:c8:5b:6e:11:ed:19:1d:a6
Signature:         BAD

It seems odd that Google would use a self signed cert here, but a cert signed by Thawte on their website. The Google CA is not in my /etc/ssl/certs. Does anyone know if this is the correct cert? Is my trusted CA list just hopelessly out of date?

Comment: What client do you use? I'm using both Mail.app and Notify and I didn't had any problems with the certificates.

Comment: Evolution, part of GNOME.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The IMAP cert is signed by a "Google Internet Authority" cert which is in turn signed by Equifax your client is not following the certificate chain of trust properly.

Comment: Or the client doesn't trust the "Equifax" root cert in question.

Comment: That's probably it, will look into it when I get home. Thanks!

Comment: @Andrew:  what turned out to be wrong?